# How to import the .sql file to PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ubuntu

i need one help.I need to import one .sql file into PostgreSQL database using Ubuntu.Now i am in the following state.

[image]

I have the .sql file already in this `/home/subhrajyoti/Sallon/sallon_test1.sql` path.In this file also the following query is present.

```
CREATE DATABASE ebdb WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

Here i need command to import this file into my postgreSQL database and chcek the data later.Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command:

```
psql -h <DATABASE_HOST> -d <DATABASE_NAME> -U <DATABASE_USER> -W -f <PATH-TO-THE-FILE>.sql
```

If you don't want the psql to prompt for a password (which is handy when you want to run the command as a Cron) pass `-w` instead of `-W` to the above command and the `psql` command will look for a `.pgpass` file in the current user home directory.

**Example `.pgpass` file content:**

```
cat ~/.pgpass 
pgdb01.example.com:5432:database-name:username:password
```

Make sure to have `0600` permission on the file.

For more information on .pgpass, See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `psql postgres < /home/subhrajyoti/Sallon/sallon_test1.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "pg_restore" command to import the database dump file into the new database:

```
 pg_restore -U postgres -d mydb -v mydb.sql
```